# Can't copy oci.dll file to C:/windows/system32

Tags: cmd, copy-paste, oracle-call-interface

As it's an ancient problem, still couldn't find good solutions for that.

I am using cmd to copy oci.dll to system32 folder.

[image]

**Access is denied** is showing. My all **oracle services** have been stopped and I am logged in a administrator account.

And as expected, I couldn't delete the oci.dll file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to solve this problem. I am posting the solution step by step as it might be helpful in future.

**Reason of the problem:**

The problem is that the file `oci.dll` which I want to copy or delete is already been fetched by one/more processes.

**Solution:**

1) Firstly, we have to figure out which process(s) is/are actually using `oci.dll` file. To check this simply go to cmd, change directory to C:\Documents and Settings, and then run tasklist/m oci.dll(or the name of the dll you facing troubles. So, in short:

```
C:\Documents and Settings>tasklist /m oci.dll
```

Running this command you can get a list of process(es) with **PID** which are using oci.dll. In my case it was-  `exploerer.exe`

So, I have to kill the explorer.exe process to copy/delete oci.dll file. A very good software [Process Exploerer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) of Microsoft could also be used for finding process regarding the .dll files and kill the processes as well.

Now, we're all set. We have to open cmd in Administrator mode and copy the oci.dll file to system32 foler.And oci.dll has been copied successfully.

[image]

**P.S.**

Ending explorer.exe you may find problems for copying. After properly killing all the explorer.exe process you may press `Ctrl+Alt+Delete` to open taskmanager  and go `File -> New Task(Run... )` to create a new task for explorer to copy/delete.

[image]

Comment: You do not usually have to kill a process to replace an in-use DLL. You should be able to rename a mapped EXE/DLL and then move or copy the new file to the old name. As an administrator you can even have the system delete the renamed old EXE/DLL at the next boot.

Comment: How can I rename a dll file which is already fetched by some process ?

Comment: There's nothing inherent in an EXE/DLL being loaded that prevents getting access to rename it. The file is opened with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` access, which allows renaming (relinking) it. Actually deleting the file fails with access denied (5) instead of a sharing violation (32) because the memory manager is what disallows it, just like it disallows deleting a paging file or mapped data file. Note also that the file security for a lot of files in System32 only grants admins RX access, so you'd have to take ownership via takeown.exe and modify the security to grant full control via icacls.exe.